# Vertx 3 : Undeploy verticles which are running in different JVM instance

Tags: java, cmd, jvm, vert.x

I've two verticles say "A" and "B". Both are running in different JVM instances.
Now, A send a message to B "Operation successful. You can undeploy yourself". When B gets this message , it should undeploy itself.

I tried two options :
1. vertx.close();
   (a) If Verticle B is opened in different command prompt.
   (b) If Verticle B is not opened in different command prompt.
2. vertx.undeploy(deploymentID(),); with Verticle B opened as different cmd prompt as well as in the same cmd prompt(A verticle cmd prompt...runs in background)

In 1->(a), Verticle B is closed but cmd prompt is still open.
In 1->(b), Verticle B is not closed and JVM is also running.
In the second case, i got below error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown deployment
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.undeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:203)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.undeploy(VertxImpl.java:587)
        at x.y.z.AVerticle.lambda$null$1(AVerticle.java:118)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$convertHandler$1(EventBusImpl.java:334)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:213)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:192)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:503)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$3(ContextImpl.java:359)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:339)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:393)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone knows how to do this?
Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure what's the use case behind this. You could simply deactivate your verticle when receiving the message from event bus. With a boolean field for status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an example for a similar case, where the requirement was to undeploy and then terminate the jvm.

https://github.com/floriankammermann/vertx-examples/tree/master/self-terminating
You can use this code too. You just have to remove the `System.exit(0);` in https://github.com/floriankammermann/vertx-examples/blob/master/self-terminating/src/main/java/org/swisspush/vertx/examples/SelfTerminated.java

A restriction here is, that you have too deploy your verticle programmatically.

In your case the verticle A and B have to be connected (can send messages to each other) over a distributed eventbus. The verticle doSomething.js is the verticle B in your case. It doesn't matter where the verticle A is deployed. The only thing that verticle A has to do, is to send/publish a message to the address "finished". This will undeploy verticle B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But in my requirement, both verticles are independent so i can't deploy it programatically as shown by you.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. I extended my answer, that you can see how it will work.